# Sequelize migration drop column before table was created

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I using Sequelize in my project. In third migration I create table `Comments` that has field named `type`. After some migrations I have a migration that dropped this field. But, when I doing `migrate:all`, `sequelize` tried to drop column before table created:

```
await queryInterface.removeColumn('Comments', 'type');
```

Some times error didn't happens. But often I get:

```
ERROR: Can't DROP 'type'; check that column/key exists
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding "sleep" in file of crushing migration before migration starts:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await sleep();
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('Comments', 'type');
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('Comments', 'type', {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      allowNull: false,
      values: commentTypes,
      defaultValue: 'comment',
    });
  },
};

function sleep() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

I know it is not good solution, but it works for me.